# What is the correct way to fail in a WebApi Controller constructor

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api, constructor-injection

I have a WebApi Controller that requires a service via it's constructor. If this service is null I would usually throw a `NullArguementException`. Is this still the correct way to fail in the context of a WebApi Controller or is there a different pattern for this.

Comment: are you using DI Container? if yes, I wonders how service is null?

Comment: I would always program defensively. It is true that in the majority of cases using a DI Container would negate this check but ultimately I cannot guarantee the usage of a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern is the same. Although with DI this will fail before calling constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am using DI but I thought I may have to hook in some specific exception.